# PDF Tron Path error for Hybrid Android App

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, pdftron, mendix

I have an issue with the path not found for PDFTron for my Hybrid Android device.
The Hybrid app is built in Mendix.

Below is my sample code.

```
WebViewer({
path: 'PDFTron/lib',
documentType: 'pdf',
//initialDoc: 'https://pdftron.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/pl/demo-annotated.pdf',
fullAPI: true,
enableFilePicker: true }, document.getElementById('viewer')).then(async function(instance) { /**** Some code here ***/ });});'
```

The above path works perfectly fine for the web version. In Android I get this error.

[image: Android Path error]

It seems like the Hybrid version does take paths with "file:///"

Can anyone guide me as to how I give the proper path for Hybrid apps or if PDFTron has some other solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

What does your file structure look like? Also do you get this error when you are using relative paths?

Best Regards